# Promise error handling: await throws unexpected error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

My intention is to dispatch a number of filesystem related tasks that will run in parallel. I save them as promises, which I await later, having given them some time to work. Unfortunately, when I await another unrelated promise any error from one of my filesystem  promises is thrown at that point.

The example below illustrates this. An uncaught error is thrown at the line `await sleep(1000)`.

How can I accomplish what I need to do?

```
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)) }

async function work() {
    const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject("p1 reject"))
    const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("p2 resolve"))

    console.log("Sleeping")
    await sleep(1000)

    console.log("Awaiting p2")
    console.log("result", await p2)

    console.log("Awaiting p1")
    try {
        console.log("result", await p1)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("caught:", error)
    }
}

work()
```

```
PS C:\test> node --version
v16.17.0
PS C:\test> node .\promise-error-handling.js
Sleeping
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "p1 reject".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
PS C:\test>
```

The problem occurs even if using Promise.all

```
function sleep(ms) { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)) }

async function work() {
    const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject("p1 reject"))
    const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve("p2 resolve"))

    try {
        console.log("Sleeping")
        await sleep(1000)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("caught sleep", error)
    }

    try {
        await Promise.all([p1, p2])
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("caught:", error)
    }
}

work()
```

```
Sleeping
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "p1 reject".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}
```

Comment: "*I save them as promises, which I await later*" - yeah, don't do that, use `Promise.all` instead. `p1` is rejected but not handled immediately, causing an `UnhandledPromiseRejection`.

Comment: "*The problem occurs even if using Promise.all*" - yes of course, you still have two sequential `await`s in your code. You'll need to write `const p3 = sleep(1000)` and only `await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])` together at once.

Comment: Are you saying that no Javascript programs can have sequential awaits?

Comment: No, they're fine in general, but you must not start the an action without immediately `await`ing it. You can also move the `await sleep(1000)` either *before* constructing `p1` and `p2`, or *after* the `await Promise.all([p1, p2])`.